# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First: Adding and updating records through a service layer

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a service class, and in this class I call my repository methods.

I got the adding of a new tutorial object to work, I just don't know how to update the record.  Here is my insert and update methods for the service:

```
public class TutorialService : ITutorialService
{
   private ITutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

   public TutorialService(ITutorialRepository tutorialRepository)
   {
      this.tutorialRepository = tutorialRepository;
   }

   public void Insert(Tutorial tutorial)
   {
      tutorialRepository.Add(tutorial);
      tutorialRepository.Save();
   }

   public void Update(Tutorial tutorial)
   {
      // Not sure what the code looks like here to call the repo methods
   }
}
```

My repository class:

```
public class TutorialRepository : ITutorialRepository
{
   PbeContext db = new PbeContext();

   public void Add(Tutorial tutorial)
   {
      db.Tutorials.Add(tutorial);
   }

   public void Save()
   {
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditTutorialViewModel editTutorialViewModel)
{
   // Other code

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("Edit", editTutorialViewModel);
   }

   // Mapping code here to Tutorial object
   Tutorial tutorial = (Tutorial)tutorialMapper.Map(editTutorialViewModel, typeof(EditTutorialViewModel), typeof(Tutorial));

   // Update the existing tutorial
   tutorialService.Update(tutorial);

   return RedirectToRoute(Url.TutorialList());
}
```

What would the update code look like?  Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your repository:

```
public void UpdateScalar(Tutorial tutorial)
{
    var original = db.Tutorials.Find(tutorial.ID);
    db.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(tutorial);
}
```

And then in your service:

```
public void Update(Tutorial tutorial)
{
    tutorialRepository.UpdateScalar(tutorial);
    tutorialRepository.Save();
}
```

Tigger's solution works too and has the benefit that it isn't necessary to load the original before updating. On the other hand setting the state to `Modified` forces that all properties are sent to the DB in an UPDATE statement, no matter if they changed or not. The solution above only sends the changed properties to the DB but requires to load the original before.

Both solutions only work with scalar properties. As soon as a more complex object graph and navigation properties are involved updating becomes more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. When EF creates your SQL statements for you, isn't there sometimes performance issues?  Can you fine tune these?

Comment: Not really related to the original question, but what is the difference between Find and Get?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt: You are pretty much bound to the SQL statements EF generates. You cannot control it. There are options though to directly send a hand-written SQL command to the server but it's only for very special situations. For "normal" CRUD operations I'd live with the EF-generated SQL. What do you mean with "Get"? `Find` loads an object by its key and if it is already loaded it returns only a reference to the object which is in the context. It's not suited for general queries. In this case a LINQ query with an `Where` operator is used normally.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the same save method in the repository class for both the insert and update for example,

```
public void Save(Tutorial tutorial)   
{   
   db.Entry(tutorial).State = tutorial.Id == 0
                                     ? EntityState.Added
                                     : EntityState.Modified;

   db.SaveChanges();   
}
```